# Laravel - 1066 Not unique table/alias on a relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to create a simple relationship between tables :

```
- attribute_type -
    id
    name

- category -
    id
    name
    description
```

So I created a pivot table to link them :

```
- attribute_type_category -
    attribute_type_id
    category_id
```

There is the model relationships :

On AttributeType.php

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\AttributeTypeCategory', 'attribute_type_category', 'attribute_type_id', 'category_id');
}
```

On AttributeTypeCategory.php

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

All seems to be fine, but I get the following error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique
>   table/alias: 'attribute_type_category' (SQL: select
>   `attribute_type_category`.*,
>   `attribute_type_category`.`attribute_type_id` as
>   `pivot_attribute_type_id`, `attribute_type_category`.`category_id` as
>   `pivot_category_id` from `attribute_type_category` inner join
>   `attribute_type_category` on `attribute_type_category`.`id` =
>   `attribute_type_category`.`category_id` where
>   `attribute_type_category`.`attribute_type_id` = 1)

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you want to create simple many to many relation between two tables 
like `attribute_type` and `category`, 
you should create three tables using migrations as you did

- attribute_type -
  id
  name
- category -
  id
  name
  description
- attribute_type_category -
  attribute_type_id
  category_id

then you will create two classes (attribute_type and category) no need to create third one for the relation.

and in attribute_type you should define method for the category relation

```
public function category() {
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');}
```

and in category class:

```
public function attributeType() {
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\AttributeType');}
```

and then you can access the categories of any attribute_type by using `->categories` and you can access the attributeTypes of any category by using `->attributeTypes`

you should follow laravel official documentation to learn  more about relations
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships