# STATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Im working on pivot table with laravel many-to-many relationship

```
public function filterByProducts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        CartRuleConditionProduct::class, 'cart_rule_condition_products',
        'product_id', 'condition_id'
    );
}
```

I can use attach, detach and sync, just like normal

```
$cartRuleCondition->filterByProduct()->sync(Product::find($request->get('product_filtered')))
```

Here is my code to calling the relationship

```
<select multiple class="form-control rounded-0" name="product_filtered[]" size="10">
   @foreach($condition->filterByProducts as $filteredProduct)
       <option value="{{ $filteredProduct }}">{{ $filteredProduct }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Here is the error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'cart_rule_condition_products' (SQL: select `cart_rule_condition_products`.*, `cart_rule_condition_products`.`condition_id` as `pivot_condition_id`, `cart_rule_condition_products`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id` from `cart_rule_condition_products` inner join `cart_rule_condition_products` on `cart_rule_condition_products`.`id` = `cart_rule_condition_products`.`product_id` where `cart_rule_condition_products`.`condition_id` = 1)
```

Please help~.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm from the sql query that dumped at error, if you want to join two same tables, one of the tables need different alias, or the SQL will be confused.

Comment: @Smankusors i know the problem but the query is generate by laravel relationship, i couldn't change it

Comment: identical problem I think [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527886/laravel-1066-not-unique-table-alias-on-a-relationship)